# Sql server not running inside docker in m1 processor

Tags: docker, apple-m1, azure-sql-edge

I am trying to make sql server run inside the docker in the mac m1 processor. Every time I am getting
exit code 1
Processor : Arm(mac m1)
docker image tried with : mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:1.0.6 and mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest
docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:1.0.6
    container_name: mssql
    volumes:
      - events_mssql:/var/opt/mssql
      - ./setup.sql:/usr/config/setup.sql
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw@rd
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
      - MSSQL_DB=events_service
      - MSSQL_USER=SA
      - MSSQL_PASSWORD=Passw@rd
      - MSSQL_DB_AUDIT_LOG=events_service_audit_log

volumes:
  events_mssql:
```

setup.sql file

```
CREATE DATABASE $(MSSQL_DB);
CREATE DATABASE $(MSSQL_DB_AUDIT_LOG);
GO
USE $(MSSQL_DB);
GO
CREATE LOGIN $(MSSQL_USER) WITH PASSWORD = '$(MSSQL_PASSWORD)';
GO
CREATE USER $(MSSQL_USER) FOR LOGIN $(MSSQL_USER);
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [$(MSSQL_USER)];
GO
```

ERROR:

```
docker-compose up
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container mssql  Created                                                                                    0.0s
Attaching to mssql
mssql  | Azure SQL Edge will run as non-root by default.
mssql  | This container is running as user mssql.
mssql  | To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2140520.
mssql  | /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: Invalid mapping of address 0x40092f5000 in reserved address space below 0x400000000000. Possible causes:
mssql  | 1) the process (itself, or via a wrapper) starts-up its own running environment sets the stack size limit to unlimited via syscall setrlimit(2);
mssql  | 2) the process (itself, or via a wrapper) adjusts its own execution domain and flag the system its legacy personality via syscall personality(2);
mssql  | 3) sysadmin deliberately sets the system to run on legacy VA layout mode by adjusting a sysctl knob vm.legacy_va_layout.
mssql  | 
mssql exited with code 1
```

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used `azure-sql-edge` it is working with this

You can use the command to bring up the docker

`docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=1" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=MyPass@word" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -e "MSSQL_USER=SA" -p 1433:1433 -d --name=sql mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge`

Answer (score 4):

Answer updated in 2023, Monday 20th.

Best option: Use Docker's Rosetta emulation mode

- Install Ventura, the newest MacOS
- Upgrade Docker to latest
- Docker Settings > General: `[X] Use virtualization framework` and
- Docker Settings > Features in Development: `[X] Use Rosetta...`
- Use `platform: linux/amd64` in Docker-compose or `--platform linux/amd6` when running containers from command line

Link to instructions: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/docker-on-apple-silicon-mac-how-to-run-x86-containers-with-rosetta-2-4a679913a0d5

Comment: Link not working, Can you please check

Comment: Hey, link is working, I just checked it.

Comment: This also works for the Apple M3 chip

Answer (score -1):

As of the time of writing this response, there is a [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/668) on this; though it was recently closed in favour of following the topic in another issue.

Comment: @TheSteed I have not seen any answer where the OP has mentioned he/she has resolved the issue. In fact as at the time of this response, I have not seen anything posted by the OP.